# Storing data from multiple functions in an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, sorting

I'm working on a payroll program that takes user input (first/last names, payrate, and hours worked) and outputs those details along with gross, tax, and net.

I have separate modules for input, calc gross, calc tax, and calc net; but I am unsure how to implement array storage so that it will include the data from each of those modules.

any help would be appreciated

*Edit:  I need to be able to sort the data (alphabetically) by employee, so what I need ( I believe) is a record of the arrays.
I have the record initialized within the main module and want the record to read something like:

> lastName[1], firstName[1] payrate[1] hours[1] gross[1] tax[1] net[1]
>
> lastName[2], firstName[2] payrate[2] hours[2] gross[2] tax[2] net[2]

I don't know how to pull the derived data from the other modules into this structure.

Comment: Do you mean you want a single array to store the user's first name, last name, pay rate, hours worked, gross pay, etc? That can't be done in C; elements of an array all have to be the same type, so you can't store strings like first name in the same array as doubles/floats like gross pay. You could create a structure for each user and create an array or linked list of user structures.

Answer (score 4):

You can just make a global structure to hold that data instead.

```
struct payroll_info
{
    char *fname;
    char *lname;
    ...
};
```

You can then just make an array of this struct and sort using `qsort()`

Answer (score 1):

***In addition to*** the struct suggestions that have been offered...,
***your question also has to do with visibility of data between files*** (modules).
***Here*** is a [great link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/what-are-extern-variables-in-c/1433387#1433387) that will clarify how to create and define information such as a struct in one file (usually a .h), assign values to the struct members and use them in another file (likely a .c) and modify the values in a third file. (likely also a .c).

As for the array of structs; Create it in a header file that will be included by any .c module that will use it.  It could look something like:

```
      #define NUM_EMPL 10 //number of employees  

      typedef struct {
        char last[40];
        char first[40];
        float payrate;
        int hours;
        float gross;
        float tax;
        float net;
    } EMPLOYEE;

    extern EMPLOYEE empl[NUM_EMPL], *pEmpl; //'extern' keyword is used only in this file
```

Then, in ***all*** .c module(s), where this struct will be used, at top of file somewhere (i.e. not inside a function), create a new instance of the struct that is defined in the .h file:

```
EMPLOYEE empl[NUM_EMPL], *pEmpl; //same as in .h file except without 'extern' keyword
```

Then, within functions you can either initialize the pointer version of the structure to the beginning of the struct definition, and populate the struct members with values;

```
void func1(void)
{
    Empl = &empl[0];  // '[0]' guarantees pointer location.

    //finally assign values   
    //(can be put into loop or similar to assign all n employess)
    strcpy(pEmpl[0].last, "Smith");
    strcpy(pEmpl[0].first, "John");
    pEmpl[0].payrate = 100.00;
    pEmpl[0].hours = 40;
    //and so on...
    //pass pointer to struct to another function
    func2(pEmpl);
}
```

Or, you receive a pointer to the struct as an argument:
(The following function can be in a different .c file to better demonstrate inter-file visibility of the data.)

```
void func2(EMPLOYEE *e)
{
    // assign values   
    //(can be put into loop or similar to assign all n employess)
    strcpy(e[0].last, pEmpl[0].last);
    strcpy(e[0].first, pEmpl[0].first);
    e[0].payrate = pEmpl[0].payrate;
    e[0].hours = pEmpl[0].hours;
    //and so on...
}
```

Comment: `char last[40];` is dangerous, because I can guarantee you that there will be someone with a longer name somewhere, no matter how long you choose your buffer to be. I would always use `char* last;` and dynamically allocate the memory for it, preferably using `asprintf()` or `%as` format string to `scanf()` if I have the glibc available.

Comment: @cmaster, I was focusing on visibility of data between multiple c modules.  But nevertheless, your point is well taken.  Thnaks

Answer (score 0):

You should use structure to store all the datas about a user.

Something like :

```
 struct user 
 {
    char *lastName;
    char *firstName;
    //other variables
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the modules are on different binary files,
then you can share the data using the `extern` keyword like so:

1. Declare the array in a single place in the code `float paychecks[12]`.
2. In order to access the data from another file, declare it like so in the importing file
   `extern float[] paycheks`
3. Do the above(2) in each file that you wish to use the paychecks array.

You should now have a single copy of the array - with everyone seeing/pointing-to the same array.